# Laravel Blade directive to properly attach to template a CSS style from 'public' folder

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade

i'm a laravel newbie, and i'm trying to import a css file into my blade template in the views folder.

I have this in the routes file:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('index');
});
```

index.blade.php in the 'views' folder has the following code in the header section:

```
{{HTML::style('css/common.css');}}
</head>
```

common.css is a file in public folder, inside a css subfolder.

The index.blade.php view runs without errors, showing up all the html elements, but without the css. What am i missing here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: It looks like the problem has to do with some .htaccess or xampp configuration.
The href generated in the page shows              [http://localhost/testLaravel/server.php/css/common.css], and that is why it doesn't get the css code. The correct path would be [http://localhost/testLaravel/public/css/common.css].

mod_rewrite is on and my .htacess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help getting rid of the server.php portion of the path would be much appretiated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try updating your template with the below fragment

```
{{ HTML::style( asset('css/common.css') ) }}
```

or manual way

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/common.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

The `asset()` function is a 'shortcut' for the public folder path.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just tried both aproaches and the same thing happens, css is not being loaded. I just tried copy and pasting the entire css content into "style" tags directly in the blade file and it works that way. I would love to be able to load this in a separate css file though...

Comment: what is the "href" value when you look at the generated html (with the above aproaches) ?

Comment: <link href="http://localhost/testLaravel/server.php/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: the href should be "localhost/testLaravel/public/css/common.css". It seems you have some mod_rewrite/htaccess issues ?

Comment: I'm now thinking this is maybe something i have wrongly configured on xampp? it seems the generated path isn't pointing to the public folder...

Comment: exactly. check your document root in virtual host settings

Comment: Gadoma thanks for your help. It seems i have mod_rewrite on (just tested it with a script i found online) and the document root is "C:/xampp/htdocs", folder in which i have the testLaravel sub-folder. Is this not right?

Comment: what is you base 'url' config ? (in app/config/app.php) It should be set to the full url of your Laravel project folder, depending on your vhost config it could be `http://localhost/testLaravel`.

Comment: It actually was simply http://localhost. I changed it to http://localhost/testLaravel, but the generated href still is http://localhost/testLaravel/server.php/css/common.css">. I'd love to get rid of this server.php portion of the path...

Comment: what is your vhost configuration and htaccess file content ? please update your question with these details.

Comment: further more, make sure you save all your files (php,css) in "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding.